# Models to list of choises

Tags: django, django-models

I have two models. One of them - events, another - experts, who lead this events.

Event model

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Article(models.Model):
    class Meta():
    db_table = 'article'

    article_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    article_anchor = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    article_text = models.TextField()
    article_date = models.DateTimeField()
```

Expert model

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Expert(models.Model):
    class Meta():
        db_table = 'expert'

    expert_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    expert_anchor = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    expert_discr = models.TextField()
```

I need to add to my Event model a some kind of Choise Field, where I can choose the Experts by name (expert_name).

Also, after that, when I open the page with Event model, I want to see all Event model fields and all Expert model fields together...

So, the main question is how can I get the list of choises with the Expert module field in another model?

Answer (score 0):

you can add a field for this to Article model `my_expert=models.ForeignKey(Expert,verbose_name="expert")`
then if you will look at this model through admin or form there will be dropdown list of choices for linkage of this article to expert.

Comment: Thx, didn't think, that it so simple to do. But have a little problem - all Expert models name looks like "Expert objects" in that list. How can I extract one field "expert_name" to fix it only for that list?

Comment: all you need is to have view to return response with template and some variables here is my example def home(request):
   
    tags = "bubu,dudu"
    description = "textstringanyhere"
    return TemplateResponse(request, "home.html", {
     
        'tags': tags,
        'description': description})

Comment: Yes, I'm understand, how to implement that into a view, and show all I need in template... But I said about admin page. Am I need to make view for admin site too to make headers looks like I want but not just "Expert objects" when I create Article model?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a foreign key. Here are the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) on them.